# why is display starting at s1->top?

Tags: c, stack

Why is `s1->top` the beginning in the display function?

```
typedef struct node* Nodeptr;
typedef char dataitem;

typedef struct node{
dataitem data;
Nodeptr next;
}Node;

typedef struct{
int count;
Nodeptr top;
}Stack_Head;

typedef Stack_Head* Stack;

Stack createStack() {
  Stack s1;
  s1 = (Stack) malloc(sizeof(Stack_Head));
  s1 - > count = 0;
  s1 - > top = NULL;
  return s1;
}

Nodeptr createNode(dataitem item) {
  Nodeptr temp;
  temp = (Nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp - > data = item;
  temp - > next = NULL;
  return temp;
}

void push(Stack s1, dataitem item) {
  Nodeptr temp = createNode(item);
  temp - > next = s1 - > top;
  s1 - > top = temp;
  s1 - > count++;
}

void display(Stack s1) {
  Nodeptr ptr = s1 - > top;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("%d", ptr - > data);
    ptr = ptr - > next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void pop(Stack s1) {
    Nodeptr temp;
    if (isEmpty(s1))
      printf("List is Empty");
    else {
      temp = s1 - > top;
      s1 - > top = temp - > next;
      temp - > next = NULL;
      free(temp);
      s1 - > count;
    }

    int isEmpty(Stack s1) {
      return s1 - > top == NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Seriously, if you cannot make __minimalist__ effort in making your question readable, why should someone bother to provide you with an answer, that too, for _free_?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows no effort of making it a proper question.

Comment: The answer is "to initialize `ptr`", but it should be rather obvious from reading the code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's not a CV reason. That's a reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `display` function is going to display all the elements in the stack and it has to start at the top because that is the only element available to it.

`ptr` is a loop variable. It starts at the top of the stack and on each iteration it is moved to the next element until it reaches the bottom of the stack i.e. a node with a NULL next pointer.

**Edit**

Why start at the top and not the bottom? Mainly because it is a lot easier. You have access to the top of the stack and each node has access to the node below it but not the one above it.

If you wanted to print it from the bottom up, it would be much harder. How do you get from the bottom item to the one above it? You can't unless you have remembered its predecessor.

The easiest way to start from the bottom is to reverse the stack first i.e. iterate through it from the top and create a new stack as you go, but it's still more work than just saying "we'll print from the top".

Comment: the s1->top is the last element added right? why did it started displaying at the top while there are others who were first?

Comment: if i push 8,9&10 it should display as 8 9 10, here.. 10 is the s1->top right? then why is ptr in the 10?

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra but when you pop them off the stack, they'll come out in the order 10, 9, 8. So who is to say what the right order is?

Comment: if i display 8,9 it should display 8 first right? while on the code, it starts backward? its pointed to 9 first, how can i traverse if it will start at the end

Comment: It is a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). You can display the items in the order they were put on or in the order they will be pulled off. It doesn't matter. In this case they are displayed in the order they wil lbe pulled off because it is easier than doing it the other way.

Comment: ok, i get it now, but am i right if i say in display, it starts from the top going down right?

Comment: I got it, thank you! so that means, my teacher displays the first to be popped first

Answer (score 0):

`display` just shows (prints) the stack. it is a choice of the implementor to start showing it from the top. Stacks normally work from the top, LIFO.

Note that if `s1` is null, the access of `Nodeptr ptr = s1 - > top;` is invalid and can cause a segmentation fault.